# Get ALIAS as concatned column names

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to concat multiple columns and get the output as single column.

example:

```
SELECT vendor_id || '|' || vendor_name FROM vendors;
```

output:

```
vendor_id || '|' || vendor_name
-------------------------------
100000001|abc_company
100000002|def_company
```

Here I am trying to get Column name as `vendor_id|vendor_name` instead of `vendor_id || '|' || vendor_name`

I tried using `AS` keyword in different ways but was unsuccessful.

when using below query, it was saying FROM keyword missing

```
SELECT vendor_id || '|' || vendor_name AS vid|vname FROM vendors;
```

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag because the `||` suggests Oracle.

Comment: If you are doing this so your reports look better, it is a lot easier (and much better) to do it in your reporting application, not in the SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* want the returned column name to be `vid|vname` you just need to quote it:

```
SELECT vendor_id || '|' || vendor_name AS "vid|vname"
  FROM vendors;
```

Note that `vid|vidname` will be case-sensitive so you'll need to specify it exactly as given if you use it elsewhere.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the output.  Personally, I don't like to have quoted column names, so I would do:

```
SELECT vendor_id || '|' || vendor_name AS vid_vname
FROM vendors;
```

However, you would do it as:

```
SELECT vendor_id || '|' || vendor_name AS "vid|vname"
FROM vendors;
```